# How to "apt full-upgrade" using a python script

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I want to be able to 1) upgrade my RPi via python and 2) catch the results (as String) to see how things went. How can I do it passing also automatically any relevant -Y responses.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(['apt', 'full-upgrade', '-y'])`

Comment: Does `import os
os.system("sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y")` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up using:

```
command = ['apt', 'full-upgrade', '-y']
result = str(subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True).stdout, 'ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import subprocess
cmd = "sudo apt full-upgrade -y"
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```